# problem accessing dynamic movieclips by name in adobe animate

Tags: actionscript-3

I've done this a million time, but here it didn't work.

I have a game_mc inside a animate.fla. inside this clip I generate a view targetareas to place stones on it. ok, the TargetArea is  a simple Movieclip inside my lib.

I can see everything, I can click on the area an get the propper name, I can get the names of the clips inside game_mc.

but I can't access it by using game_mc[clipname]

```
for (var i:int = 1; i<= 20; i++){
    var targetArea:TargetArea = new TargetArea();
    targetArea.txt.text = String(i);
    var modu = ((i-1) %5);
    targetArea.x = 100 + modu * 340;
    var abs = int((i-1)  / 5);
    targetArea.name = "targetarea_" + String(i)+ "_mc";
    targetArea.mouseChildren = false;
    targetArea.y = 100 + (abs * 200) ;
    game_mc.addChild(targetArea);
}

for(var x:int=0;x < game_mc.numChildren;x++) {
    trace (game_mc.getChildAt(x).name);
}

for (var i:int = 1; i< 20; i++){
    var targetName:String = "targetarea_" + i + "_mc"               
    trace( game_mc[targetName].x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the name you assign your TargetArea instances isn't automatically converted
into a property of the DisplayObject you attach it to. As far as I remember though this
nonchalant way of accessing MovieClips using array access used to work prior to AS3.
The more elegant solution is to retrieve the child using getChildByName().

```
trace(game_mc.getChildByName(targetName).x);
```

Additionally, in case game_mc is an instance of MovieClip or a dynamic class you can make the TargetArea instances a property of it using:

```
game_mc[targetArea.name] = targetArea;
```

This way you can access them using **game_mc[name].property** afterwards.